# Graph Has Two / Three Different Minimal Spanning Trees?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I'm trying to find an efficient method of detecting whether a given graph G has at least two different minimal spanning trees. I'm also trying to find a method to check whether it has at least 3 different minimal spanning trees. The naive solution that I've though about is running Kruskal's algorithm once and finding the total weight of the minimal spanning tree. Later , removing an edge from the graph and running Kruskal's algorithm again and checking if the weight of the new tree is the weight of the original minimal spanning tree , and so for each edge in the graph. The runtime is O(|V||E|log|V|) which is not good at all, and I think there's a better way to do it.

Any suggestion would be helpful, thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16572681/graph-has-two-three-different-minimal-spanning-trees

Comment: As Alex J Best points out, you have posted this question [here on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16572681/1090302). Please note that [crossposting between multiple SE sites is highly frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068). Try one site first, and if you don't get a satisfactory response, ask a moderator to **migrate** the question to a different site.